Terraform Azure - Error deploying AKS NoRegisteredProviderFound
I am trying to deploy an AKS cluster using this terraform code.
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
  name                = local.k8s.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.k8s_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.k8s_rg.name
  dns_prefix          = local.k8s.dns_prefix

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  tags = local.k8s.tags
}

And I am tired to search for a solution to this error message

azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s: Creating...
╷
│ Error: creating Cluster: (Managed Cluster Name "assessment-cluster" / Resource Group "assessment"): containerservice.ManagedClustersClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="NoRegisteredProviderFound" Message="No registered resource provider found for location 'centralus' and API version '2022-01-02-preview' for type 'managedClusters'. The supported api-versions are '2017-08-31, 2018-03-31, 2019-02-01, 2019-04-01, 2019-06-01, 2019-08-01, 2019-10-01, 2019-11-01, 2020-01-01, 2020-02-01, 2020-03-01, 2020-04-01, 2020-06-01, 2020-07-01, 2020-09-01, 2020-11-01, 2020-12-01, 2021-02-01, 2021-03-01, 2021-05-01, 2021-07-01, 2021-08-01, 2021-09-01, 2021-10-01, 2022-01-01, 2022-02-01, 2022-03-01, 2022-04-01, 2022-06-01, 2022-07-01, 2022-07-02-preview, 2022-08-01, 2022-08-02-preview, 2022-08-03-preview, 2022-09-01, 2022-09-02-preview, 2022-10-02-preview, 2022-11-01, 2022-11-02-preview, 2023-01-01, 2023-01-02-preview, 2023-02-01, 2023-02-02-preview, 2023-03-01, 2023-03-02-preview, 2023-04-01, 2023-04-02-preview, 2023-05-01, 2023-05-02-preview, 2023-06-01, 2023-06-02-preview, 2023-07-01, 2023-07-02-preview, 2023-08-01, 2023-08-02-preview, 2023-09-01, 2023-09-02-preview, 2023-10-01, 2023-10-02-preview, 2023-11-01, 2023-11-02-preview, 2024-01-01, 2024-01-02-preview, 2024-02-01, 2024-02-02-preview'. The supported locations are 'australiacentral, australiacentral2, australiaeast, australiasoutheast, brazilsouth, brazilsoutheast, canadacentral, canadaeast, centralindia, centralus, eastasia, eastus, eastus2, francecentral, francesouth, germanynorth, germanywestcentral, israelcentral, italynorth, japaneast, japanwest, jioindiacentral, jioindiawest, koreacentral, koreasouth, northcentralus, northeurope, norwayeast, norwaywest, polandcentral, qatarcentral, southafricanorth, southafricawest, southcentralus, southindia, southeastasia, swedencentral, switzerlandnorth, switzerlandwest, uaecentral, uaenorth, uksouth, ukwest, westcentralus, westeurope, westus, westus2, westus3'."
│
│   with azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s,
│   on aks.tf line 12, in resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s":
│   12: resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {

If you know what I am doing wrong, wow, that would be awesome. I don't know why I am facing this error message or where do I need to look at because the error message is not really helping at all.

Consider to ask sys-admin questions (e.g. about creating kubernetes clusters) on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

check your provider has registered with Microsoft.ContainerService under its subscription @Robert

az provider show -n Microsoft.ContainerService -o table &
az provider register --namespace Microsoft.ContainerService
Follow by check this 
